# Add another object to link_to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks to an earlier answer I have the following code in a view.

```
 <%= @miniature.contents.where(miniature_id: @miniature).map { |content| link_to content.miniset.name, content.miniset }.join(", ").html_safe %>
```

That outputs

```
`Minisetname, Minisetname, Minisetname`
```

I want to add `(" x#{content.quantity}")` after the linked `Minisetname`so that it appears as

```
Minisetname (x3), Minisetname (x7), Minisetname (x4)
```

I only want it to append the `(" x#{content.quantity}")` if `content.quantity` is not null.

I do this elsewhere in a block but I can't work out how to do it with the above array.

Comment: Seems like controller logic in a view layer.

Comment: @wurde actually it would probably be helper logic since miniature seems to be the model.

Comment: I'll got back through at some point prior to launch and move a lot of logic into helpers and controllers. I've not got the hang of helpers yet and barely have anything in them.

Comment: @WorldOfProper sounds like results of cowboy coding. If your writing code that someone will have to maintain then bite the bullet and invest in your skills. I'd recommend starting with Rails guides and railscasts by Mark Bates.

Comment: No cowboys here. Only a me, learning. I'm not handing it over for anyone to maintain. I follow both rails casts and Rails guides and have spent months on this. I maybe shouldn't have been so flippant in such a frowny forum but I'm not leaving tons of bad code in the wrong places, rather in this case trying to get a working version before I refactor it. Perfection seems lower down the priority list than learning and understanding.

Comment: God I wish that wasn't the last thing I read on a friday night after busting my arse on coding all week. Grateful everyone else on here more positive/encouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assuming that you have set up the relationships in your models normally I don't really see why you should need that `where`.

I would then have structured the code something like this:

**View**

```
<%= content_miniset_links_with_quantity(@miniature) %>
```

**Helper**

```
def content_miniset_links_with_quantity(miniature)
  miniature.contents.map{|content| content_miniset_link_with_quantity(content)}.join(', ').html_safe
end

def content_miniset_link_with_quantity(content)
  string = link_to content.miniset.name, content.miniset
  string << "(x#{content.quantity})" if content.quantity.present?
  return string
end
```

Comment: The above is giving me `undefined method 'content'`. Highlighting the line `<% miniset_link_with_quantity(content.miniset) %>`. Adding the  `where` back in doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have updated the code example so that it should work.

Comment: Amazing. That is exactly what I was after. Fantastic. I'll be sure to use the helpers like this in future. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You just put both of them in a string following link_to

```
link_to "#{content.miniset.name} #{content.quantity}", content.miniset }.join(", ").html_safe
```

Just make sure though that you're not labeling something that's not `html_safe`.

EDIT: To have it appear after is easy.

```
<ul class="items-list">
<% @miniature.contents.where(miniature_id: @miniature).map do |content| %>
   <li class="item-holder">
    <ul class="item-details">
     <li class="item-link"><%= link_to content.miniset.name.html_safe, foobar_url(content.miniset.id)  %>,</li>
     <li class="item-quant">(x<%= content.quantity %>)</li>
    </ul>
  <li>,
<%end%>
</ul>
```

Note, you don't actually need the divs, or to do it multi-line but that's just better style. Oh, and the second div might better off being a span, or both inner div's might be better as span's but you get the idea.

OH!! I just looked at your where condition. So, that's unlikely to be necessary (unless contents is some weird non-obvious function you wrote). `@minature.contents` will load the inner joined association automagically.

OK, so here's using the join.

```
<% @miniature.contents.where(miniature_id: @miniature).map do |content| %>
  <%= link_to content.miniset.name, foobar_url(content.miniset.id)  %> (x<%= content.quantity %>)
<% end.join(", ") %>
```

Comment: That works but I'm really trying to make `x#{content.quantity}` appear after the link and not be linked text.

Comment: @WorldOfProper I updated the answer to better reflect what you are going for.

Comment: I'd forgotten that you could put divs in a block but your code there will put the `quantity` AFTER the `join(", ")`, I was trying to get it before the `join(", ")` but not inside the link.

Comment: No problem, but if this works for you would you mind accepting it as the correct answer?

Comment: It doesn't do the thing that I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are they not producing the info or are they on different lines? If they're just on different lines then that's because you would use css to line them up. And actually, in that case you'd want a ul instead of the outer div, and the inner divs would be li's.

Comment: The inner divs would be wrapped in one li

Comment: It renders the (x5) after the comma. It wants to be inside the comma but outside the link.

Answer (score 0):

first thing, dont use `where` clause in view. It's a bad code. And, when you do `<%= =>` it actually output anything. You are using `map` function which returns `array`. you should rather rearrange and do your work in this way.

```
<%= @miniature.contents.where(miniature_id: @miniature).map { |content| link_to "#{content.miniset.name} (x#{content.quantity})" , content.miniset if content.quantity.present? }.join(", ").html_safe %>
```

Comment: To avoid using `where` I'd have to do this in the controller right? Is it possible to have the `x#{content.quantity}` appear after the link and not be linked text?